# Local version of Google Maps API

Tags: c++, google-maps, mapping, gis

Do you guys know if there is a version of the Google Maps API for C++ which works using local maps rather than having to connect to a Google server?

The application is the plotting of GPS positions in an area with no internet coverage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can tell you that there's definitely no such thing - you need a GIS/mapping engine and a dataset. If it has to be free, OpenStreetMap is probably your best bet for the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative for Google Maps, you might want to have a  look at [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page).
(See also the usage and software sections [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStreetMap#Usage))

Answer (score 1):

You can download and store map tiles (png files) using the [google maps static API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/), and then reread those once stored images without reconnecting to the server. You'll have to write the whole download and management stuff yourself (i.e. using [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) for download etc. - i don't know of such a library), and you probably need to acquire a Google premier license, as google strongly restricts the anonymous usage of the static api. But technically thats possible.